# how to get exact answer from ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some ajax requests in my jquery code. and my php server should decide what to do. but I'm beginner in web programming I don't know how to return the exact response .

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#subButton').click(function () {
      var query = "query";
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'info.php',
        datatype: 'text',
        data: {query: query},
        complete: function (data) {
          alert(data);// it returns the whole php page!
        }
      })
        .done(function (data) {
          alert("done");
        })
        .fail(function () {
          alert("Posting failed.");
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

and there is my php code

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'music' ] ) ) {
  echo "music";
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'query' ] ) ) {
  echo "query";
}
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'url' ] ) ) {
  echo "url";
}
?>
```

in this jquery I want just the word "query" not whole page. and also I want to know how to set it in html through some tags.

Comment: what file extension has your php page got? sounds like it might be `.html`

Comment: @DevDonkey .html yes!

Comment: thatll be why. it needs to be `.php`.

Comment: It's a web application and need .php and mysql

Comment: @DevDonkey but this is part of code is for testing weather it works? I want some one to chat with. this is a game web application and I don't khow which kind of ajax to use? and how to design quick way respoding?

Comment: @DevDonkey I thought wrong about your first question! sorry.
html and jqury are in file.html  and php server side is in info.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so we've found out why your php page is returning the whole script. It had a `.html` extension, not a `.php` one.  Without the php extension the server would just send back the whole lot.

how to put it into a tag? Quite easy.

suppose you have a tag on your page like this (note the id):

```
<h2 id="main_heading">some heading</h2>
```

all you need to do is ask jquery to place the response inside it like this.

```
 complete: function (data) {
      // select the object with the right ID and change its innerHTML
      $('#main_heading').html(data); 
 }
```

this will replace the contents of the `<h2>` with whatever comes back.

**update**

if youre having trouble, try putting a `console.log` call in and check it with the browsers javascript console, this should show you whats being sent back from the server.

like this:

```
 complete: function (data) {
      console.log(data);


      // select the object with the right ID and change its innerHTML
      $('#main_heading').html(data); 
 }
```

Comment: but my info.php doesn't have .html tag anymore. and no .html extension.
the jquery code has .html extension!

Comment: Im confused. Whats actually happening now?

Comment: "so we've found out why your php page is returning the whole script. It had a .html extension"
but it doesn't have .html extension! :(

Comment: and it has a `.php` extension now?

Comment: Excuse me! console.log shows ( 200 success) . but shows [object object] and [object XMLDocument]. what 's your idea?

Comment: But response text is whole page of <?php ....?> ! so maybe it needs header on php first line!